# What is the difference between packable down jackets?

Tags: gear

I've noticed a lot of similar looking packable down jackets this year, and I don't know if this is a new style or if I haven't been paying attention, but I'm wondering if there's a big difference to them, how much the "down number" matters "(650, 700, 800), or if it's just price discrimination and they're all manufactured by the same company.

I've noticed that Patagonia has one with 700 down for ~220, OR has one with 700 down for about $140, Eddie Bauer has one with 800 down for $120, and there's even a Cole Haan one for $50 at Costco that claims to keep you warm "down to -3 degrees" (which is actually about the temperature I'm looking for).

My instinct is to go with a better brand, but I got the Eddie Bauer because their guarantee allowed me to trade in my 2 year old coat for a new jacket.

Is there any way to objectively test which is going to be warmer and lighter?